# Ecnrypt in Java - decrypt in python. AES

Tags: python, java, encryption, aes

I'm trying to decrypt some info from Java code

Java encryption:

```java
public static String encrypt(String value) {
    Key key = generateKey();
    byte[] encValue = new byte[0];
    Cipher c;
    try {
        c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        System.out.println(c.getBlockSize());
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        encValue = c.doFinal(value.getBytes());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchPaddingException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        log.error("Can't encrypt", e);
    }
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encValue);
}
```

Here is  the Python decryption code:

```py
def decrypt_aes(self, encrypted_str):
    _iv = "\x00" * AES.block_size
    generator = AES.new(str.encode(self.key), AES.MODE_CBC, self._iv.encode())
    encrypted_str_bytes = base64.b64decode(encrypted_str)
    recovery = generator.decrypt(encrypted_str_bytes)
    return unpad(recovery, block_size=AES.block_size).decode()
```

With small encrypted text, all is OK (such as cV6aNGlm3u2sDW+z74y0uA==), but with long encrypted data, it always results in an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\utility\Crypt.py", line 25, in <module>
    a = c.decrypt_aes(st)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\utility\Crypt.py", line 18, in decrypt_aes
    return unpad(recovery, block_size=AES.block_size).decode()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 2: invalid continuation byte
```

What am I doing wrong?

p.s. even if i'm trying to decode like [:16] bytes  of encrypted same error

Comment: Are you sure it was actually UTF-8? Your Java code uses `getBytes()`, which makes it use the platform default character set, which is not necessarily UTF-8 (at least, not in Java 17 or earlier, especially on Windows). You should always be explicit (e.g. `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Comment: In Java the cipher is initiated with "AES" only that means ECB mode. Just change the mode in python from CBC to ECB mode and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Fehr solution

> In Java the cipher is initiated with "AES" only that means ECB mode. Just change the mode in python from CBC to ECB mode and you should be fine

Worked perfectly. After changing mode from CBC to ECB all worked well